# Finding Prime Divisors C++

Tags: c++, loops

I set out to write a project that would find all the prime divisors for a given input number.

```
int checkPrimeDivisors = 0;
int x = 0;

bool isPrime(int someNumber) {
    bool status = true;
    for (int z = 2; z <= sqrt(someNumber); z++) {
        if (someNumber % z == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}


int main() {
    cin >> x;
    for (int someNumber = 1; someNumber < x; someNumber++) {
        if (x % someNumber == 0 && someNumber == isPrime(someNumber))
            cout << someNumber << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code I've come up with. The loop for works when I check for all divisors and omit the && someNumber == isPrime(someNumber), but once I add that conditional check it doesn't print the divisors at all. 
I can't seem to figure out what's the problem, help will be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated: Repeatedly calling is prime is going to be murderous. Look into using a prime number sieving algorithm and caching the results.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to accomplish by comparing the numbered entered into `x` with a boolean result from `isPrime()`. Can you try [explaining that to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Comment: In your `isPrime` function you never use the `status` variable. And instead of `sqrt` you could just do `z * z <= someNumber` which would be cheaper than computing the square root.

Comment: You can start your loop at 3 and increment by 2.  All even numbers except 2, are not prime.

Answer (score 1):

`isPrime(someNumber)` returns a boolean. The boolean will almost never be equal to `someNumber` itself. There's no need for the `==` test, just:

```
if (x % someNumber == 0 && isPrime(someNumber))
```